# alertmanagerconfig matches about namespace not work

Tags: kube-prometheus-stack

my alertmanagerconfigs:

```yaml
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1alpha1
kind: AlertmanagerConfig
metadata:
  name: configlinkflowalertmanager
  labels:
    alertmanagerConfig: linkflowAlertmanager
spec:
  route:
    groupBy: ['alertname']
    groupWait: 30s
    groupInterval: 5m
    repeatInterval: 12h
    receiver: 'webhook'
    matchers:
      - name: alertname
        value: KubePodCrashLooping
      - name: namespace
        value: linkflow
  receivers:
  - name: 'webhook'
    webhookConfigs:
    - url: 'http://xxxxx:1194/'
```

the web shows: namespace become monitoring ? why? and alerts only in monitoring can send out
can I send other namespace or all namespace alerts?

```yaml
route:
  receiver: Default
  group_by:
  - namespace
  continue: false
  routes:
  - receiver: monitoring-configlinkflowalertmanager-webhook
    group_by:
    - namespace
    match:
      alertname: KubePodCrashLooping
      namespace: monitoring
    continue: true
    group_wait: 30s
    group_interval: 5m
    repeat_interval: 12h
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a [feature](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/discussions/3733):

> That's kind of the point of the feature, otherwise it's possible that alertmanager configs in different namespaces conflict and Alertmanager won't be able to start.

There is an [Issue (#3737)](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/issues/3737) to make namespace label matching optional / configurable. The related [PR](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/pull/3821) still has to be merged (as of Today), but it will [allow you to define global alerts](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/pull/3821/commits/394a7fda78f1ab7f7024f16d0662f16b2249989c#diff-fa30b606fa314e622b98cf54f4b916737e9fc6e87b01bbb5c7e888333eb9c9ea).